# CRXDE Lite - Adobe Experience Manager 6.2 Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 m

Tags: google-chrome, adobe

someone has a problem with CRXDE Lite panel properties in Chrome? When I open my Chrome browser this panel moves from the bottom of the screen up and at one point this panel is invisible on the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Same happens to me. The zoom out may cause the problem in Chrome.
Try to restore your zoom in/out by clicking `Ctrl + 0`.